# Google search with python does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, google-search

I have such function, I need to search in google some phrase which I`m getting with BS4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import google

google.LICENSE_KEY = 'some_key'


def scrape(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response and response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        name = ' '.join([_.strip() for _ in soup.find('h1').text.split('\n')])

        search_list = google.doGoogleSearch(name, maxResults=5)
        for i in search_list.results:
            print i.title
            print i.url
```

But I`m receiving such output:

```
  File "/home/likewise-open/LVIVSOFT/okoval/PycharmProjects/Merry/start.py", line 16, in scrape
    search_list = google.doGoogleSearch('google', maxResults=5)   File "/home/likewise-open/LVIVSOFT/okoval/proto_for_merry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygoogle/google.py", line 421, in doGoogleSearch
    outputencoding )   File "/home/likewise-open/LVIVSOFT/okoval/proto_for_merry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygoogle/SOAP.py", line 3621, in __r_call
    self.__hd, self.__ma)   File "/home/likewise-open/LVIVSOFT/okoval/proto_for_merry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygoogle/SOAP.py", line 3538, in __call
    config = self.config)   File "/home/likewise-open/LVIVSOFT/okoval/proto_for_merry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygoogle/SOAP.py", line 3472, in call
    raise HTTPError(code, msg) SOAP.HTTPError: <HTTPError 404 Not Found>
```

I have tried to create new License Keys but it always the same